# How to stop a NodeJs file on Ubuntu server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I paid someone to install a Js script on my server
but when i tried making some changes on scripts/files i just couldnt see the changes on browser
while browsing and googling for like 24 hours i figured out that js scripts should be restarted in order to show the result on browser
and i figured out that in order to start a node js file i should type in terminal

```
node /dir/example.js
```

but can someone help me how to refresh/restart it
Iam stuck here like 24 hours
please help

I just want to let you know too that iam using Putty software in order to connect to the ubuntu server, ubuntu version is 20.04

Comment: try `Ctrl + C`?

Comment: try Ctrl + C where ? , iam using Putty to connect to the server

Comment: i dont want to close the whole node js server because i dont really think iam able to put it all back on function, i just want to refresh that file

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: you will need an ssh connection to your server with access to a terminal..

Your node.js scripts, if they are on a server, should typically be ran using a process manager such as pm2.

Try to type `pm2 list` in a terminal. If you see some information you have hit the spot. Just after that run `pm2 restart id`. `id` being the number of your process and your changes should be visible.

You can just try this or try your luck with other process managers that run on your server providers. Just read what your server provider recommends for default and usually your previous developer would have used it.